# Dispatcher rewrites for 2 different content paths

Tags: apache, adobe, aem

How to setup dispatcher rewrites for 2 different content paths in aem with single dns name.Can anyone help me with the setup on this using apache 2.4

Comment: Maybe you can explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: For Example:content path of one site is /content/canada and  another site content is  under /content/new-canada . I want to use same dns name to serve the content from both the content paths.

Comment: I do not think this can be achieved at the dispatcher level since different content paths map to different folders, but with Apache, you can serve from different paths and make them as if coming from the same "domain", but this will rely too much on Apache rules.

Comment: What is your use case? A relaunch?

Comment: Yes similar to relaunch. wanted to server contain from same domain with two different contents of that site